# Randomnly swapping items betwen lists

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I'm working on a small script that involves changing one codon (a item on my list) to another, randonmly. 
I start by converting the DNA sequence into a list of codons, and then I want the script to choose a random one  and change it to another from a list of codons. The problem is that it only works for the first time that said item apears on the list. (Even if it chooses the last item, it replaces it for the first items that appears on the list that  is equal to that item). 
I don't know if I have been clear enough, I'm still learning. 
Here's the code:

```
import random 


codones = ['ATA', 'ATC', 'ATT', 'ATG', 
           'ACA', 'ACC', 'ACG', 'ACT', 
           'AAC', 'AAT', 'AAA', 'AAG', 
           'AGC', 'AGT', 'AGA', 'AGG',                  
           'CTA', 'CTC', 'CTG', 'CTT', 
           'CCA', 'CCC', 'CCG', 'CCT', 
           'CAC', 'CAT', 'CAA', 'CAG', 
           'CGA', 'CGC', 'CGG', 'CGT', 
           'GTA', 'GTC', 'GTG', 'GTT', 
           'GCA', 'GCC', 'GCG', 'GCT', 
           "GAC", 'GAT', 'GAA', 'GAG', 
           'GGA', 'GGC', 'GGG', 'GGT', 
           'TCA', 'TCC', 'TCG', 'TCT', 
           'TTC', 'TTT', 'TTA', 'TTG', 
           'TAC', 'TAT', 'TGC', 'TGT', 
           'TGG']


dna = "atgaaaagcatgaaaagc" 
DNA = dna.upper()

print(DNA)

print("El gen tiene " + str(int(len(dna)/3)) + " Aa:")

def codones_dna(seq):
    codon = []
    for i in range(0, len(seq), 3):
        codon.append(seq[i:i +3])
    return codon
lista_codones = codones_dna(DNA)
print(lista_codones)

def translate(seq):
    table = { 
        'ATA':'I', 'ATC':'I', 'ATT':'I', 'ATG':'M', 
        'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T', 
        'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K', 
        'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',                  
        'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L', 
        'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P', 
        'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q', 
        'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R', 
        'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V', 
        'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A', 
        'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E', 
        'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G', 
        'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S', 
        'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L', 
        'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 
        'TGG':'W' 
    } 
    protein = " "
    if len(seq) % 3 == 0:
        for i in range(0, len(seq), 3):
            codon = seq[i:i + 3]
            protein += table[codon].lower()
    return protein
protein = translate(DNA)
print(protein)


def mutation(seq):  
    for i in range(0, len(seq), 3): 
        dna_mut = seq[i:i]
        wt = random.choice(lista_codones)
        mutado = random.choice(codones)
        if wt != mutado:
            dna_mut += seq.replace(wt, mutado, 1)


    return dna_mut

dna_mut = mutation(DNA)
```

Comment: You have a list of codons and want to change those condons to the values of the same list?

Comment: Can you show sample expected data?

Comment: You have a string of a dna sequence and you want to change that to a random sequence in your sequence list?

Comment: I want to change on of the codons to another, that comes from another list.

Comment: Yes, for example: Given the sequence "dna = "atgaaaagcatgaaaagc", i change one of the codons (notice that the sequence repeat it selfs). The mutation generated can be, for example, ATG(GAG)AGCATGAAAAGC (It changed aaa to gag). The problem is that it can't do it to the second part, when the sequence repeat itselfs, in other words, it will never target the  second "aaa" in the sequence.

Comment: No, i want to change only 3 bases of the whole sequence, that is why i divide it into a list, to only pick the bases (items) from the dna.

Comment: You want to change 1 random 3-letter sequence in the string, to a random value of your list?

Comment: Excactly. That random value being another 3-letter sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this line:

```
print("El gen tiene " + str(int(len(dna)/3)) + " Aa:")
```

is terribly redundant, it does the same as:

```
print("El gen tiene", len(dna)/3, "Aa:")
```

only in less readable way. Second, your mutation function should be like:

```
def mutation(seq):  
    dna_as_list = [ seq[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(seq), 3) ] # here you split seq into codons
    wt = random.choice(lista_codones)
    mutado = random.randint(0,len(dna_as_list)-1) # here you generate a random index
    dna_as_list[mutado] = wt # replace the codon at the generated index
    return ''.join(dna_as_list)
```

Comment: Holly balls i believe it works! The problem was that i wanst using the index right? Thank you so much! I have to delete the spaces from the new string so it can be coded to a protein with the translator and it's good to go! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be of use:

```py
import re
from random import randint


codones = ['ATA', 'ATC', 'ATT', 'ATG', 
           'ACA', 'ACC', 'ACG', 'ACT', 
           'AAC', 'AAT', 'AAA', 'AAG', 
           'AGC', 'AGT', 'AGA', 'AGG',                  
           'CTA', 'CTC', 'CTG', 'CTT', 
           'CCA', 'CCC', 'CCG', 'CCT', 
           'CAC', 'CAT', 'CAA', 'CAG', 
           'CGA', 'CGC', 'CGG', 'CGT', 
           'GTA', 'GTC', 'GTG', 'GTT', 
           'GCA', 'GCC', 'GCG', 'GCT', 
           "GAC", 'GAT', 'GAA', 'GAG', 
           'GGA', 'GGC', 'GGG', 'GGT', 
           'TCA', 'TCC', 'TCG', 'TCT', 
           'TTC', 'TTT', 'TTA', 'TTG', 
           'TAC', 'TAT', 'TGC', 'TGT', 
           'TGG']

dna_sequence = 'atgaaaagcatgaaaagc'


def replace_random_seq(dna: str, replace_list: list):
    sequences = re.findall("\w\w\w", dna)  # searches for 3 letter pattern in dna

    ran_index = sequences[randint(0, len(sequences)]  # get a random index of a sequence
    sequences[ran_index] = replace_list[randint(0, len(replace_list)]  # replace the item in the random index with a random sequence in the sequences list

    new_dna = ""
    for item in sequences:
        new_dna += item

    return new_dna

print(replace_random_seq(dna_sequence, codones))
```

Just used regex to find all 3-letter patterns and replace one with a different one from your list.

Comment: As I understand it, the three-character sequence must be a complete codon, i.e. it must start at an index divisible by 3.

Comment: Ohhhh, okay. I didn't know that.

Comment: @Błotosmętek I fixed it now. I think this should work  just fine in a few lines of code :)